# Getting locale entities hibernate hql

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql, hibernate-mapping

I got this db model and I would like getting Continent and get Countries through main object for a specific language. I have wrote a SQL sentece which returns countries successfully (wrapped on Object[][]) but as I said above I need Continent->ContinentLocale->Country->CountryLocale and I'm not able to write the correct HQL

I use Hibernate 4.3.5

**SQL sentence**

```
select C.idcountry, CL.name,D.idcontinent,DL.name from country C 
inner join country_locale CL on c.idcountry=cl.idcountry and cl.idlanguage=2 
inner join continent D on c.idcontinent=D.idcontinent 
inner join continent_locale DL on D.idcontinent=DL.idcontinent and DL.idlanguage=2;
```

[image]

**Continent.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="continent")
public class Continent implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="IDcontinent")
private Integer idContinent;

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="IDcontinent")
private Set<Country> countries;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="primaryKey.continent")
private Set<ContinentLocale> continentLocale;
}
```

**ContinentLocale.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="continent_locale")
@AssociationOverrides({
@AssociationOverride(name = "primaryKey.continent", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "IDcontinent")),
@AssociationOverride(name = "primaryKey.language", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "IDlanguage"))
    })
public class ContinentLocale implements Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private ContinentLocalePK primaryKey=new ContinentLocalePK();

@Column(name="name",nullable=false,length=50)
private String name;

@Transient
public Continent getContinent(){
    return getPrimaryKey().getContinent();
}

public void setContinent(Continent continent){
    getPrimaryKey().setContinent(continent);
}

@Transient
public Language getLanguage(){
    return getPrimaryKey().getLanguage();
}

public void setLanguage(Language language){
    getPrimaryKey().setLanguage(language);
}
   }
```

**Country.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="country")
  public class Country implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="IDcountry")
private Integer idCountry;


@OneToMany(mappedBy="primaryKey.country")
private Set<CountryLocale> countryLocale;
}
```

**CountryLocale**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="country_locale")
@AssociationOverrides({
@AssociationOverride(name = "primaryKey.country", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "IDcountry")),
```

@AssociationOverride(name = "primaryKey.language", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "IDlanguage"))
        })
     public class CountryLocale implements Serializable{

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private CountryLocalePK primaryKey=new CountryLocalePK();

@Column(name="name",nullable=false,length=50)
private String name;

@Transient
public Country getCountry(){
    return getPrimaryKey().getCountry();
}

public void setCountry(Country country){
    getPrimaryKey().setCountry(country);
}

@Transient
public Language getLanguage(){
    return getPrimaryKey().getLanguage();
}

public void setLanguage(Language language){
    getPrimaryKey().setLanguage(language);
}}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I just find the solution and for above mapping the hql sentences are:

**Getting country locales**

HQL="select distinct CL from Continent D inner join D.continentLocale DL inner join D.countries C inner join C.countryLocale CL where CL.primaryKey.language.idLanguage=2"

**Getting continent locales**

HQL="select DL from Continent D inner join D.continentLocale DL where DL.primaryKey.language.idLanguage=2"